# Android - how to stop ListView.setAdapter(); interrupting scroll view?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've got a ListView with a method (`public ArrayAdapter<String> populateListView(){}`) to update the Adapter. Every 500ms I call `lv.setAdapter(populateListView();`. This works, but if I'm scrolling down the ListView, when the method is called it resets my view and automatically scrolls me to the top. So if I'm 80% down my ListView, when the method is called I'm reset to 0%.

How do I continually populate my ListView without resetting the scroll position?

I've already tried calling `lv.getScrollY();` before setting the adapter and then `lv.setScrollY();` but this doesn't help. I've also tried calling `lv.scrollTo(0, scrollY);` but this doesn't help.

How do I stop resetting the scroll position when updating the adapter?

Comment: Every `500ms`? Are you mapping our journey through the universe in real-time?

Comment: In any case, the listview scroll position resets when you call `setAdapter(...)`. Have you looked into `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Also, the `setScroll()` and `scrollTo()` methods have to be posted to the View => mListView.post(new Runnable() { ... }). Place the `lv.scrollTo(0, scrollY)` call inside the `run()` method of the `Runnable`. `500ms` is quite alarming. Consider switching to a less-drastic unit of time.

Comment: @Vikram well considering Android saves system files approximately every tick I need to update these values fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the items in the adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() instead of creating a new adapter.

Example:

```
adapter.replaceItems(yourNewListWithData);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You have to implement the replaceItems method yourselves.

```
public void replaceItems(List<? extends E> newItems) {
    entries.clear();
    entries.addAll(newItems);
}
```